# Question about the essential supremum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say $f: E \to \bar{\mathbb{R}} $ is measurable function. Define the Essential Supremun $esssup f$ as $ \inf \{z : f \leq z \; \text{a.e.} \} $

a.e. means almost everywhere which means everywhere except on sets of measure zero.

MY question is: While studying the concept I have made the following remarks based of the definition. Are they correct? thanks in advanced for any generous response.

THe $esssup f $ can be $\infty$ and this happens if $\{z : f \leq z \; \text{a.e.} \} = \varnothing $, which occurs when $ f > z$ a.e. Also, $esssup f$ is $- \infty$ if $\{z : f \leq z \; \text{a.e.} \} = \bar{\mathbb{R}} $ which occurs when $f \leq z$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remarks are ill-founded: In "$\{z:f\leq z \mbox{ a.e.}\}=\emptyset$, which occurs when $f>z$ a.e.", you need to quantify the second $z$. Also, the negation of $f\leq z$ a.e. is not $f>z$ a.e., it's $f > z$ on a set of measure greater than zero.

You should instead say something like,

> The essential supremum of $f$ can be $\infty$, and this happens if $\{z:f\leq z\mbox{ a.e.}\} = \emptyset$, which occurs if for every $z$, there exists a set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ and $f|_E > z$.

Similar remarks hold for your second point.